# Launching RETINA simulator from Xcodebuild for continuous integration

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, ios-simulator, xcodebuild, retina-display

I'm running automated application unit tests under a C.I. environment for iPhone apps and everything works fine using a command line such as;

```
xcodebuild -scheme "Tests" -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator5.0
```

That's great, but I now want to force the iPhone simulator to launch in Retina mode, rather than the default standard mode.

I know I can toggle this with the hardware menu option, however I'm running this on a headless integration server so don't have that option.

What I'd like to do is pass a switch somehow on the command line that tells the simulator to launch in Retina mode.

I optimistically tried appending SimulateDevice="iPhone (Retina)" to the xcodebuild command, but that seems not to work.

Is this possible? I can't seem to find a way at the moment.

If it's not possible, is there an alternative approach I can take?

Comment: Is your **xcodebuild** command actually launching the app in the simulator?  Tell me how!

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/1365687 and http://lifeandcode.net/2011/12/automated-ios-jenkins-builds-with-application-tests-and-core-data/ and http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/04/17/xcode4-running-application-tests-from-the-command-line-in-ios/ for some of the references I followed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use AppleScript to change the value of `SimulateDevice` in `com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist`.

Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/1168261) that does that after prompting the user to choose the desired device type. You can modify it to read the value from the command line or use `"iPhone (Retina)"` as a default value.

The following script changes the simulator device into a value from the command line:

```
on run argv

set selectedDevice to item 1 of argv as string

set thePListFolderPath to path to preferences folder from user domain as string
set thePListPath to thePListFolderPath & "com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist"
tell application "System Events"
    tell property list file thePListPath
        tell contents
            set value of property list item "SimulateDevice" to selectedDevice
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

end run
```

And you can execute it from the terminal using the command `osascript`:

```
osascript myScript.scpt "iPhone (Retina)"
```

Or

```
osascript myScript.scpt "iPhone"
```

**Edit**

You can modify that script to make it launch the Retina simulator by default:

```
set selectedDevice to "iPhone (Retina)"

set thePListFolderPath to path to preferences folder from user domain as string
set thePListPath to thePListFolderPath & "com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist"
tell application "System Events"
    tell property list file thePListPath
        tell contents
            set value of property list item "SimulateDevice" to selectedDevice
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Finally note that changes to `"SimulateDevice"` take effect only when a new simulator is launched.

Comment: Liking the approach ... on Lion this doesn't work though. It looks like arch -i386 osacript ... will do the trick though. Now I'm getting script error: Expected “end” or “end tell” but found unknown token. (-2741)

Comment: OK so I'm actually using the defaults write option as that was easier, but you absolutely set me on the right track, and I needed applescript for the restart, so I'm happy to accept this answer - many thanks for taking the time to expand on your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach looks like;

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator "SimulateDevice" '"iPhone (Retina)"'
```

However as with the applescript approach from sch, this doesn't seem to be quite working when used as part of the build phase. Still investigating ...

Comment: Neither seem to work as part of a run script, I'll try the restarting simulator bit though... but how do I do that from the command line?

Comment: Solved the restarting simulator with another script from here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125243/how-can-i-reset-the-ios-simulator-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 2):

For anyone scripting in Ruby, here is a method to set the simulated device in the simulator:

```
  def set_simulated_device(simulated_device)
    current_simulated_device = `defaults read com.apple.iphonesimulator "SimulateDevice"`.chomp

    if current_simulated_device != simulated_device
      simulator_pid = `ps -ax|awk '/[i]Phone Simulator.app\\/Contents\\/MacOS\\/iPhone Simulator/{print $1}'`.chomp
      Process.kill('INT', simulator_pid.to_i) unless simulator_pid.empty?
      `defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator "SimulateDevice" '"#{simulated_device}"'`
    end
  end
```

**List of Arguments that can be used**

"iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)"

"iPhone Retina (4-inch)"

"iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)"

"iPad"

"iPad Retina"

"iPad Retina (64-bit)"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the iPhone Simulator binary

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateDevice "iPhone Retina (4-inch)"

for other versions:

- "iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)"
- "iPhone Retina (4-inch)"
- "iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)"
- "iPad"
- "iPad Retina"
- "iPad Retina (64-bit)"

Comment: this opens the simulator correctly... but how do we proceed further as we wont gain controll till we close it

Comment: If you launch instruments and the simulator is already running it will use the running version of the simulator

Answer (score 0):

not telling any answers are wrong.. but this worked for ios 7

```
-- START:choose.sim.device
on run argv
    --set simType to item 1 of argv
    tell application "iPhone Simulator"
        activate
    end tell
    set simType to "Ipad Retina (64-bit)"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iOS Simulator"
            tell menu bar 1
                -- Hardware menu bar item
                tell menu bar item 5
                    -- Hardware menu
                    tell menu 1
                        -- Device menu item
                        tell menu item 1
                            -- Device sub menu
                            tell menu 1
                                click menu item simType
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    -- END:choose.sim.device

    -- Need to show the simulator again after changing device,
    -- or else the simulator be hidden when launched by instruments
    -- for some odd reason.
    tell application "System Events"
        set visible of process "iPhone Simulator" to true
    end tell

    -- START:choose.sim.device
end run
-- END:choose.sim.device
```

Note: its not "iPad" its "Ipad"

Comment: I got this from somewhere too.. and i forgot where

Answer (score 0):

Pro-tip, create an alias.

```
alias ios="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator  -SimulateDevice”
```

Example:

```
ios "iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)"
ios "iPhone Retina (4-inch)"
ios "iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)"
ios "iPad"
ios "iPad Retina"
ios "iPad Retina (64-bit)"
```

Comment: Why would creating an alias be considered a pro-tip?  Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the device with the -destination flag:

```
xcodebuild -scheme "Tests"      \
           -configuration Debug \
           -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6"
```