# Running ios-sim with Jenkins

Tags: shell, permissions, jenkins

I'm trying to start my app from the command line using [ios-sim](https://github.com/downloads/pegli/ios-sim/ios-sim-xcode4.3.tar.gz) but this is what I get:

```
Started by user User
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/UI Testing/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/h4/ws64t3bx2nnds4pg3345xrr000009c/T/hudson6341279754557259451.sh
+ /Users/myUser/Desktop/ios-sim launch /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Project_Monkey_Build/workspace/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectMonkey.app

    [DEBUG] Could not start simulator session: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=5
 "Operation failed with underlying error 4294956486." UserInfo=0x1001b1760 
{NSLocalizedDescription=Operation failed with underlying error 4294956486., 
NSUnderlyingError=0x1001a3390 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (OSStatus error -10810.)"}
```

It looks like a permission problem as I can run the same command from terminal and it works fine. I've also tried to give full 777 permission to ios-sim and the MonkeyTalk directory,but still nothing.

Any idea?

Comment: there is something here https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim/issues/5 but quite old

Comment: Having the same problem here, working in terminal but not through Jenkins. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be related to the Jenkins process not having a "display". Try running Jenkins as a user logged in to the desktop, then run the ios-sim again.

Unload Jenkins from launchd:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Then run Jenkins from a terminal:

```
sudo su jenkins -c "JENKINS_HOME=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home /Library/Application\ Support/Jenkins/jenkins-runner.sh"
```

If this works, you can make Jenkins always run as a logged in user by moving the launchd job config file from `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist` to `~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

Comment: To get this working with Xcode 6.1.1 and Yosemite I removed the `GroupName` and `SessionCreate` keys. Also, I ensured that jenkins was the owner of the file, just to be sure.

Comment: is there a way to make this work with slaves launched via ssh?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862327/on-a-mac-sierra-how-can-i-give-an-ssh-session-access-to-the-display

Answer (score 1):

I know this post was from a while ago, and not sure if anyone is checking it, but I also ran into this issue recently and it turned out that there was a duplicate app already in the iphone simulator creating an issue and not letting the new app run.

I reset the simulator and it then worked.  I then added the applescript to reset the simulator each time before running ios-sim.  this script can be found here...

[How can I reset the iOS Simulator from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125243/how-can-i-reset-the-ios-simulator-from-the-command-line)

Scroll down the answer that has 13 up votes next to it, not the one that was checked marked.

Hope this helps someone in the future..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only workaround it's to run the command as super user:

```
sudo /Users/myUser/Desktop/ios-sim launch /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Project_Monkey_Build/workspace/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectMonkey.app
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem and found that jenkins user is not correctly set up to run test case on simulator. Follow instruction given on below website:

http://pivotallabs.com/ios-ci-jenkins/

see the section "SETTING UP THE JENKINS USER".

hope it will work for you as well.