# Reset iOS Simulator with Applescript

Tags: ios, applescript

Im trying to reset the iOS-Simulator using AppleScript. When I just run a script to `Reset Content and Settings` it just resets the current version of the iOS-Simulator (e.g. 6.0). I need to reset each iOS version in the iOS Simulator to remove all the apps. I can only use Applescript and cant delete the apps from the Simulator using bash (deleting the app folders)

Thanks

Comment: Or there is an alternative, delete all folders present inside Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1. Hope it helps you..

Comment: I can only do it using AppleScipts because this will be runnning on our build server. cant delete it manually

Comment: Can't you create AppleScript to make contents of particular folder empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I present,

## [The Definitive iOS Simulator Reset Script (link)](https://github.com/stianhoiland/The-Definitive-iOS-Simulator-Reset-Script/)

[image]

> Based on [Oded Regev's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14811280/659310) from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125243/how-can-i-reset-the-ios-simulator-from-the-command-line) (which was based on [Jacob Rus's fine "menu_click" code](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060921045743404))

Comment: Is this meant for simulator only or it is applicable to devices also? Currently i am looking for an similar solution which will clear all installed applications and browser cache from iOS devices, any suggestion.Thanks

Comment: You should post a new question for that, raaz :)

Answer (score 0):

Stian's script has not been updated for iOS 7 and the dialog isn't necessarily useful for build scripts. I've borrowed heavily from his code and written a version that is relatively future-proof to new devices and iOS versions.

https://github.com/michaelpatzer/ResetAllSimulators