# Wrong build being deployed on Android device using Visual Studio 2012 Xamarin.Android

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Xamarin.Android Beta release to develop an Android application. When I try to deploy the android application for debugging purposes onto an Android device, it deploys the previously built application on the device and not the recent changes I made and deployed (i.e No refresh of build). However, if I use Xamarin Studio to do the same, it deploys the correct build everytime (i.e refreshes the build with new code changes).

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. My solution was to add "deploy" to the build configuration:

> BUILD => Configuration Manager... => (select "Debug" from left-hand combo-box) => (tick "Deploy" in grid)

Courtesy of this [xamarin forum post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7387/visual-studio-2012-and-xamarin-android-application-is-not-reinstall-in-device-during-debuging).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue: With Visual Studio 2019 the debug version of my driver was deployed while building the release version.

The cause of my problem was, that in the *Properties -> Driver Install -> Package Files* I had an absolute path pointing to the debug version of my driver in the column *File*. This setting is valid for all configurations (not separated for debug/release), and when entering macros, they are immediately expanded to absolute paths.

I fixed this by editing the .vcxproj file with my favourite editor and changed the path back to `$(TargetPath)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it does this, I had this issue before. I also noticed that the device log was somewhat behind (ie, at 3.30pm, the last record on the device log was 11.00am).

Uninstalling the app from the device and re-deploying it seems to correct it.

Note: I had this issue in VS, didn't check with XS.

I would look at the difference in your deployment settings in VS and XS (I think it may have something to do with the Fast Deployment option).

Comment: I am only having this issue with VS. It doesnt seem to uninstall the previous version of the application on the device. Thanks for your input! I will check it out and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

Similar question (though for iOS Simulator) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973860/xamarin-ios-simulator-running-old-code).

I had a similar problem (though on an Android emulator).

What **didn't work for me**:

- restarting the computer
- restarting Visual Studio
- deleting bin / obj folders
- going into Configuration Manager (Debug / Release / Configuration Manager) and ticking everything there - everything was ticked
- changing the version of the app in the manifest

What **worked for me**?

**Uninstalling the app from the emulator and then running Debug again**.
It was an Android emulator, so I uninstalled by clicking on the app icon and holidng for long, and then dragging it to "Uninstall App". On an iOS simulator it should be similar.