# Unable to run unit tests from command line in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xcode6

I use the following command to run unit tests in my app:

xcodebuild  -project myapp.xcodeproj -scheme "myapp Simulator" -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR='build' clean test

From logs it looks like the the unit tests are not even executed , but the result says ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

I have updated command line tools as well. Not sure how to get the unit tests executed. Is there something i need to change in the command?

Comment: I am using this command from jenkins. This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380365/timeout-when-running-xcodebuild-tests-under-xcode-6-via-ssh

Answer (score 0):

Did you see an error like this:
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphonesimulator7.1" cannot be located.

You need to update your simulator version to 8.0:

xcodebuild -project myapp.xcodeproj -scheme "myapp Simulator" -sdk iphonesimulator8.0 CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR='build' clean test