# xctool doesn't install app using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, xcodebuild, xctool

Xctool is not working in my Jenkins' job (v 1.598) but it works using Terminal

This is the command line:

```
xctool -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=8.1,name=iPhone 6' -reporter pretty -reporter json-compilation-database:compile_commands.json -reporter junit:Build/junit.xml clean test OBJROOT=./Build
```

This is the error:

```
[Info] Collecting info for testables... (1249 ms)
  run-test TestingProject.xctest (8.1, iPhone 6, application-test)
    [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'com.domain.app' but failed. (54 ms)
    [Info] Preparing test environment failed; will retry 2 more times (0 ms)
    [Info] Verified iOS Simulators... (0 ms)
    [Info] Shut down iOS Simulator... (0 ms)
    [Info] Stopped any existing iOS simulator jobs to get a fresh simulator. (7 ms)
    [Info] Reset iOS simulator content and settings at path "/Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/144B4DFF-8E5D-4685-AF80-4970F634E7A8/data" (127 ms)
    [Warning] Tried to install the test host app 'com.domain.app' but failed. (13 ms)
```

I'm using xctool 0.2.2 and the weird part of this is that I'm running the same Jenkins' job in my local machine and it works fine.

Comment: Have you installed all certificates on jenkins?

Comment: @Opal the same command line works in terminal (installing & testing in Simulator), I think the issue is related to xctool because it can't launch iOS Simulator

Comment: I resolved this issue with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26031521/3281423 ... my Jenkins was being executed by using LaunchDaemons instead of LaunchAgents. LaunchAgents are able to run GUI apps, in this case iOS Simulator