# Xcode 6.4 simulator does not need LaunchAgent workaround any more?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator, xcodebuild, xcode6.4

From this answer I did some workaround 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26031521/677596

for xcode 6.3 and below

> You can also use launchd for running tests on the iOS simulator from a
>   SSH session, either by crafting a LaunchAgent and manually loading /
>   starting that, or by using "launchctl submit”.

Now after switching to xcode 6.4, this workaround is causing some transient issue when running tests:

```
2015-07-27 18:20:10.024 xcodebuild[82019:35808239] Metadata.framework [Error]: _MDAccessCopyClientPort failed retrying
2015-07-27 18:20:10.024 xcodebuild[82019:35810614] Metadata.framework [Error]: couldn't get the client port

Testing failed:
    Test target VoyagerTests encountered an error (Test session exited(-1) without checking in. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/zj/17v5xz0n44j10tnn0tzbq8380000gq/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest-status/Session-2015-07-27_18:20:02-vjq6dO.log)
```

But if I just run the tests without loading LaunchAgent, it works fine then. Has anyone experienced the same things? Does it mean Xcode6.4 has fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are referring to was an issue in Xcode 6.0 through Xcode 6.2.x.  It was addressed in Xcode 6.3.

You are possibly encountering another bug with _MDAccessCopyClientPort, so I suggest you file a radar for that at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This kind of information is so hard to find:(