# Reset iOS app from commandline

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I'm building a tool for building an iOS app and running UIAutomation on it. So far I've been targeting the iOS Simulator and I've run into a hiccup moving to running on real devices.

I have a feature where the tool reinstalls the app between each test, so that it always runs from an uninitialized and known state, which currently uses `xcrun simctl uninstall` and obviously doesn't work for real devices. I'm looking for something similar for real iOS devices.

Another working solution would be to reset the app through some nifty command.

I'm not interested in any UI based solutions, it has to run from a commandline.

Comment: Could this be related

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125243/how-can-i-reset-the-ios-simulator-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

[iDeviceInstaller](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller) supports uninstalling/installing on real devices.

Uninstall:

```
/usr/local/bin/ideviceinstaller -U <app_bundleID> -u <device_UDID>
```

Install:

```
/usr/local/bin/ideviceinstaller -i <pathToIPA> -u <device_UDID>
```

Answer (score 0):

We wrote [an automation bridge](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/tree/master/pod/PPAutomationBridge) in Illuminator that should allow you to send arbitrary commands to your application (in both the simulator and on real hardware).

It is accessed via the command line through [a ruby script](https://github.com/paypal/Illuminator/blob/master/scripts/UIAutomationBridge.rb).